# Any Independent Tools to check HTTP Headers

Tags: debugging, http, http-headers

After using this tool dating from 2002 the past years, I felt the need for an upgrade.
This tool checks simply the head of a url. Im would prefere a browser-indepentant software that works regardless of my Opera/Ie/Safari and as long as it works on windows 7. *(please don't advise browser-dependant addons like LiveHttpHeaders which works only on FF3.6 and older)* let alone on other browsers.

Any fast, snappy, independant tool doing similar like this, which might be less than eight years old, with bit more capabilities is an answer! Thanks for your suggestions.

http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/viewhead/

[image]

Comment: Why does it have to be browser-independent? There are lots of built-in and add-on tools on modern browsers.

Comment: Wow, I love this tool, I had been looking for something dead simple like this, thanks for sharing. And, I think as long as the tool still works, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use `curl`:

```
curl -I -L http://stackoverflow.com
```

Failing that, something like [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `HEAD` utility from the Perl package [`libwww-perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/) for years and find it meets my needs:

```
$ HEAD http://stackoverflow.com/
200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 08:32:37 GMT
Vary: *
Content-Length: 190652
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 08:21:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 08:20:00 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2011 08:32:38 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.34.119.12:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

Of course, if you don't already have Perl installed, it might be too much hassle for a simple little tool. The package also comes with `GET` and `POST` utilities, as well as some more fully-formed programs.